Importing participants gives success message but data is not imported
When importing participant information from the Courses...Import Participants menu, the import process says successfully completed but when I review each contact's records the imported data is not reflected in the contact's record. The imported data has the contactID, ParticipantID, StudentID, CourseID, Status, and a custom field that is associated with the course.
When I look in the MYSQL database, the import creates a table, 'civicrm_tmp_d_dflt_xxxxxxxxx' with the information that should have been uploaded, but the information doesn't actually import or show in the contact's record. The custom field is a yes or no option field.
The import has always worked. It's stopped working after upgrading from CiviCRM 5.68.1 to CiviCRM 5.74.5
Has anyone experienced this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am running CiviCRM 5.75.0, Wordpress 6.5.5, PHP 8.1.29, MySQL 8.0.36-28.
